# Dynamic function return type based on input - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following TypeScript code. Here is a deeply nested object with some `specialKey` keys.

```js
const obj = {
  THIS: {
    IS: {
      MY: {
        OBJECT: {
          DUDE: {
            specialKey: 'foo',
          },

          specialKey: 'bar',
        },
      },
    },
    CANNOT: {
      BE: {
        specialKey: 'baz',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I have a function that parses this structure and generates an object with the keys concatenated together wherever there is a `specialKey` key.

```js
const result = parseObj(obj);
/*
  result = {
    THIS_IS_MY_OBJECT: true,
    THIS_IS_MY_OBJECT_DUDE: true,
    THIS_CANNOT_BE: true,
  }
*/
```

Here's the function for reference:

```js
const parseObj = (obj: {}): any => {
  const root = {};

  const inner = (obj, prefix = ''): void => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (key === 'specialKey') {
        root[prefix] = true;
      } else if (key === key.toUpperCase()) {
        inner(obj[key], prefix === '' ? key : `${prefix}_${key}`);
      }
    });
  };

  inner(obj);
  return root;
};
```

So this code works, but since it's so dynamic, I need to use `any` as the return type, so there's no Intellisense for `result`, so I can't type `result.~~~~` and get code completion for the object keys above. Is it possible to create a type or rework the function so I don't need to use `any`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this that I'm aware of; TypeScript is not that dynamic.

However, based on your example the values are always booleans, so you can slightly improve the return type:

```
interface ObjectSummary {
  [key:string]: boolean
}

const parseObj = (obj: {}): ObjectSummary => {
  const root: ObjectSummary = {};
  // ...
```